# Ubuntu 14.04 and Qt5: No QMenu objects show up!

Tags: 14.04, qt5

I have installed the Qt5 packages from the Ubuntu (14.04) official repository:

```
sudo apt-get install qt5-default qttools5-dev-tools appmenu-qt5
```

Then I found this critical bug: QMenu objects don't show up in the Qt applications GUI. You can reproduce this issue compiling and running these examples:

1. http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qtwidgets-mainwindows-menus-example.html
2. http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qtwidgets-mainwindows-application-example.html

Anyone else can confirm this issue or is it just me?

Note: If I use the bundled Qt5 installer directly from the Qt Project website, I don't get this bug.